# pandoc convert html with style sheet to docx

Tags: html, converters, docx, pandoc

I've been banging my head on this one for a few hours, and I'm sure the solution is quite simple, or non-existent.

I'm trying to convert an html file to docx!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
}

h1 {
    color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I can convert it no problem, but I can't get the styles to stick.

```
pandoc -s myfile.html -o test64.docx
pandoc -s -c myfile.css myfile.html -o test64.docx
```

Please save me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above answer no longer works.  According to the documentation, you now produce the template using:

```
pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > custom-reference.docx
```

For the full documentation of how to use the template, go to [the documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) and search for "--reference-doc"

Answer (score 8):

In your command the "-c myfile.css" would only be used if you were  writing to HTML or HTML 5. It is a writer specific option.

For docx formatting you need to create a ".docx" template.

Start by running `pandoc -D docx > my_template.docx` and then edit the styles in my_template.docx.

Finally run `pandoc -s myfile.html --template=my_template -o test64.docx`

Comment: I tested this solution and it doesn't retain the color of the font in a simple HTML file.

Comment: Could you give some more details as to what you tried.

Comment: @BlackFrog did you find any solution?

Comment: Did this work? Is there any other way to preserve styling when converting from HTML to docx?