# Convert html to docx using pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I trying to convert this html

`<p><font color = \"#808080\">SHILPI</p>`

to docx using pandoc with this command

```
pandoc -s -o "test.docx" -t html5 -t docx html_file
```

But its losing colors, I am getting only text, as far as I know I think html code is correct because when I am using wkhtmltopdf to convert same html to pdf it gives the proper color. What can be the issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You question is a duplicate of [pandoc convert html with style sheet to docx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483060/pandoc-convert-html-with-style-sheet-to-docx/29484938#comment53356815_29484938) but I cannot get the solution to work.  Therefore I don't think it is fair to link to solution that doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

That's not how Pandoc works, it doesn't understand CSS, only HTML/Markdown. It preserves the content, but not the layout etc, see [semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).

You can, however, use [templates](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates) to style your output consistently. With Word it's a bit more complicated but you can use the [--reference-doc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc) option for mostly the same effect.

Comment: Thank you but my document varies everytime that's why i don't want to use reference docx.

Comment: I see, it's still the correct answer though :) (edited post to add link to semantic HTML).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
pandoc  -s -S test.htm -o test.docx
```

Reference: http://pandoc.org/demos.html

Comment: I get now ` pandoc -f markdown+smart -t markdown-smart.`

Answer (score 0):

This inspection highlights deprecated HTML tags and provides ability to replace them with CSS or with other tags for some of them.
Maybe better use this:
`<p style="color: #808080">SHILPI</p>`

Comment: No this is wrong html input its not even working in webpage.

Comment: if i not mistake, this a good example for learn all current notations http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-search-and-replace